# Kafka consumer is failing with Error deserializing Avro message with unknown protocol

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

In my use case, i had created JDBC kafka connector, pulled the data from oracle table and sucessfully pushed to kafka topic but when i try to read the messages from this kafka topic i get the deserialization issue as listed below.

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 2
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: localhost
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:593)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:124)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:188)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:330)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the schema registry URL in the YAML configuration file. Notice `unknown protocol` error

Change it to this (note I added the `http://` protocol to the URL line), and it should work:

```
schema:
  version: latest2
  registry:
     url: http://localhost:8081
```

Comment: @mjuarez- Thank you! It solved the problem. Thanks for the quick response!